# Div: enlarge and resize back to original on hover out

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to expand a div to a particular size on hover in and I want the div to go back to its original size on hover out, using the animate function.

Is there any way by which I could calculate the original size of the div to be used in animate?

Comment: If you enlarge it to the size of the screen, it'll be impossible to hover off it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to store the original state outside/before your eventhandler:

```
var origHeight = $("div").outerHeight(true);

$("div").hover(function(e){
    $(this).stop().animate({
        height: e.type === "mouseenter" ? $(window).height() : origHeight
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/b5HUU/2/

By the way, it's not an good idea to do that on hover... Because there's no space for the mouse to leave (except the whole browser).

**Update**

So it's better to use a click-event:

```
var origHeight = $("div").outerHeight(true),
    clickState = false;

$("div").click(function(e){
    clickState = !clickState;
    $(this).stop().animate({
        height: clickState ? $(window).height() : origHeight
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/b5HUU/4/

Comment: when we mousover div so many times .. it will continuously animate

Comment: @rab You can add `.stop()` in front of the animation-handler. I've updated my example.

Comment: thanks! 

also is there any way by which i could change it from hover to click (click on div and away from it)?

Comment: @stark Is your question answered for now? Then mark it as it is! :)

Answer (score 0):

you need to `stop` animate on `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`

```
var w = $('#an').width(),
    n = w + 100 ; // particular size

function widthAnimate( width ){
    return function(){
        $('#an').stop().animate({
            width : width +'px',
        });
    }
};

$('#an').mouseenter( widthAnimate( n ) )
       .mouseleave( widthAnimate(w ));
```

Added this in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d9feW/)

Comment: `jQuery.fn.stop` is in no case a part of his question ;)

Comment: thanks! 

also is there any way by which i could change it from hover to click (click on div and away from it)?

Comment: @stark try some code .. if you have code issue, we will help you